# How to show the following KeyValuePair in the unity editor(so that it is editable)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

In a bitesize: I have a KeyValuePair that I want to display and make editable in the Inspector.

I have the following implementing class of my custom Key value pair.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
namespace Unit.Properties
{
    public class ClassificationPropertySuperClass : MonoBehaviour, IClassificationUnitProperty
    {
        [SerializeField]
        KeyValuePair<UnitClassifications, float> value;

        public KeyValuePair<UnitClassifications, float> GetComponentValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void SetComponentValue(KeyValuePair<UnitClassifications, float> value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And just for information this is the custom KeyValuePair class I made

```c#
[System.Serializable]
public class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public KeyValuePair()
    {
    }

    public KeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now the core of the issue is that I cannot edit these values in the inspector. For the designers this is an absolute must. I would love to create a editor script too add this functionality but I get kinda lost when it comes to those. Anyone willing to help me out?

Just for reference this is how they appear now in the Inspector

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Inspector can't display/edit Properties by default.

Instead of

```
public TKey Key { set; get;}
public TValue Value { set; get; }
```

use

```
public TKey Key;
public TValue Value;
```

It than should be editable in the Inspector.

---

In newer versions you also can do

```
[field: SerializeField] public TKey Key { set; get;}
[field: SerializeField] public TValue Value { set; get; }
```